# How do contravariant types work in golang 1.18 with generics?

Tags: go, generics, covariance, contravariance

In golang 1.18 I would like to define a function like follows:

```golang
func Pipe[A, T1, T2 any](left func(A) T1, right func(T1) T2) func(A) T2 {
    return func(a A) T2 {
        return right(left(a))
    }
}
```

e.g. the output of the `left` function should be the input of the `right` function, repesented as generics.

I am noticing that this fails to work as expected for the following example:

```golang
func OpenFile(name string) *os.File {
...
}

func ReadAll(rdr io.Reader) []byte {
...
}

var OpenRead = Pipe(OpenFile, ReadAll)
```

This fails to compile because the compiler considers `T1` to be `*os.File` and although it's compatible to `io.Reader` it's not identical.

If I were to invoke the chain without templates like so:

```golang
var result = ReadAll(OpenFile("test"))
```

then the compiler identifies the compatible types.

Questions:

- is there a way in golang 1.18 generics to fix the signature of `Pipe` to allow for the desired behaviour?
- is the golang 1.18 behaviour by design or is this a bug?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Hopefully this will evolve over time ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No.
2. No, not a bug. See the [FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#covariant_types).

Given that Go does not support covariant result types you'd need to convert the result of the `left` to the type accepted by the `right`. However there's currently [no way to express convertibility](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#no-way-to-express-convertibility) using type parameters.

If you want you could adapt your code based on the example in that link and you'll get something like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/Pezvctnb2Pb), but keep in mind that it's not "compile-time type-safe".

```golang
func Pipe[A, T1, T2, T3 any](left func(A) T1, right func(T2) T3) func(A) T3 {
    return func(a A) T3 {
        return right(any(left(a)).(T2))
    }
}
```