# Go: own List type incompatible with own Functor type

Tags: list, go, generics, functor

In order to learn more about Go, generics, and functional programming, I implemented a `List` type (excerpt of `list.go`):

```golang
package funcprog

type Function[T any] func(T) T

type List[T any] []T

func (l List[T]) Map(f Function[T]) List[T] {
    var ys List[T]
    for _, x := range l {
        y := f(x)
        ys = append(ys, y)
    }
    return ys
}
```

Which works quite well (`main.go`):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "funcprog"
)

func main() {
    numbers := funcprog.List[int]{0, 1, 2, 3}
    twice := func(x int) int { return x * 2 }
    fmt.Println(numbers.Map(twice))
}
```

```bash
$ go run main.go
[0 2 4 6]
```

My `List` is actually a `Functor`, so I wrote this interface (`functor.go`):

```golang
package funcprog

type Functor[T any] interface {
    Map(Function[T]) Functor[T]
}
```

However, If I want to use my `List` as a `Functor` (`main.go`, modified):

```golang
import (
    "fmt"

    "funcprog"
)

func demo[T int](f funcprog.Functor[T]) {
    fmt.Println(f.Map(func(x T) T { return x * 2 }))
}

func main() {
    numbers := funcprog.List[int]{0, 1, 2, 3}
    demo[int](numbers)
}
```

I get this error:

```
funcprog.List[int] does not implement funcprog.Functor[int] (wrong type for Map method)
    have Map(f funcprog.Function[int]) funcprog.List[int]
    want Map(funcprog.Function[int]) funcprog.Functor[int]
```

Isn't my `List[int]` also a `Functor[int]`, because `List[T]` satisfies `Functor[T]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking if a type implements an interface, go does not try to do "interface mapping" on the elements of the signature of that function, it only compares the exact signatures.

If you want to have your `List[T]` type implement your `Functor[T]` interface, you should change the signature of the `Map()` method :

```
func (l List[T]) Map(f Function[T]) Functor[T] {
    ...
}
```

---

To mention one extra point : this is not linked to generics, but to how type checking is implemented on interfaces.

Here is another example (without generics) :

```
type MyStr string

// MyStr implements fmt.Stringer
func (s MyStr) String() string {
    return string(s)
}

// but this method does not fulfill the Concatter interface below
func (s MyStr) Concat(x string) MyStr {
    return s + " " + MyStr(x)
}

type Concatter interface {
    Concat(s string) fmt.Stringer
}

var _ Concatter = MyStr("") // compilation error
```

https://go.dev/play/p/tKDGEXlYHyl

Comment: Thanks, that did work! It also makes sense, because the returned type `Functor` is more general than `List`, which allows for further definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The types in the function signatures must match exactly. So you simply need to change the return type of `List.Map` method to return a `Functor[T]`.

```
func (l List[T]) Map(f Function[T]) Functor[T]
```

This now compiles because `List[T]` does implement *exactly* `Functor[T]` with its own `Map` method, and both instantiations of  `demo` and `List` share the same concrete type.

Fixed playground: https://go.dev/play/p/a4GeqXstjct

> Isn't my List[int] also a Functor[int], because List[T] satisfies Functor[T]?

Yes it is, however Go generics [don't support any form of type variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72086935/how-do-contravariant-types-work-in-golang-1-18-with-generics), therefore by returning `List[T]` as in your example the method signature differs from that of the interface.